# Sandboxed AND stackless python?

Tags: python, jit, continuations, pypy, python-stackless

I need a scripting language for describing very complicated workflows.

- These workflows need to be paused
  whenever user input is required, and
  resumed after it is given (could be
  months later).  Seems like serializable continuations from Stackless would be a good fit.
- Users also need to be able to edit
  the workflows themselves. I'm not sure how serialized continuations would handle underlying code changes. I think I might need to save the Git version hash along with the continuation, and only 'upgrade' a continuation at checkpoints where no state is needed.
- I prefer the Python syntax since
  readability is a very high priority,
  and dynamic features are key. I'm open to suggestions, though.
- Eventually I'll probably write a visual flow-chart editor that maniupulates the underlying code.

I've looked in depth at Stackless and PyPy. Stackless doesn't seem to offer any promises of sandboxing, while PyPy seems to offer both stackless and sandboxed, but I can't find any mention of having **both at the same time.**

Any solutions? If there's an expert out there who can get me going with a good solution, I've got a paypal account and I'm willing to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your serialization requirement will be difficult in most languages with native co-routine libraries. You might need to implement co-routines in another way to allow for object graph serialization.

Lua has the Pluto library, which CAN persist threads (co-routines): http://lua-users.org/wiki/PlutoLibrary

As far as "safe" execution in a sandbox, [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) is a first choice. You can have multiple lua states in a single application with zero issues, and it supports co-routines in the language. It also has the benefit of being quite fast in its VM form, and with [luajit](http://luajit.org/) is [competitive with Java JIT](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/which-programming-languages-are-fastest.php?gpp=on&javasteady=on&luajit=on&java=on&lua=on&python3=on&calc=chart) in many cases.

Comment: Serialization is the key feature I'm looking for. It's touted by lots of languages. Java has JavaFlow, for example.  
But I've found that advertised features and practical functionality can be very different. I'm hoping someone has experience using said features.

Comment: @Computer: Try Pluto for Lua - it claims to be able to serialize lua_states. http://lua-users.org/wiki/PlutoLibrary

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Know any usage instances?